# Some multimedia keys stop working

Tags: gnome, sound, keyboard

I have the problem with with Mute and VolumeDown keys in Ubuntu 14.04 on my Thinkpad X61. These two keys just stopped working after relogin.

I tried to run `gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys` for my user, but this did nothing.

Keys are hardware OK (I can see them pressed by `xev` and also can use them as hotkeys in Audacious, also they work correctly for the Guest session). But system wide I can raise but not lower volume using keys. In **Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts** Ubuntu can delete and set up these keys again, so the system does see them. They just do nothing for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

Was resolved by restarting Unity (`unity` command in Alt+F2 dash). Which is strange as neither relogin, nor shutdown and start of the laptop resolved the issue.

If somebody can explain this, please do! I still need the correct way of resolving the issue.